# Mapping a square texture to a triangle

Tags: objective-c, graphics, opengl-es, texture-mapping

I started to play with a OpenGL ES 1.0 and I run into some (beginners) problem: I tried to map a square texture to the cube described by triangles.

```
    // Turn necessary features on
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    //glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  

    // Bind the number of textures we need, in this case one.
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

//Drawing code
static GLfloat rot = 0.0;

static const Vertex3D vertices[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f, //0  00  
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f, //1  10
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, //2  11
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, //3  01      
};


static const int vertexCnt = 3 * 2;

static const GLubyte cube[] = {
    3,0,2,
    1,2,0,
};

static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0,1,
    0,0,
    1,1,
    1,0,
    1,1,
    0,0,
};


glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
//glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);


glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

//glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);



glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCnt, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cube);


glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
//glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Now, after a zillion attempts, I just can't get it work for other sides...
Is there some rule of thumb for case when mapping square texture to triangles?

EDIT: I think I figure out how the mapping should be done. But it doesn't work for this example (one face). Can someone just please verify if I done mapping correctly (assuming that the rest of code is working)?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a way to neatly map a square onto a cube while reusing the same vertex data. I would rework your cube as 6 separate quads = 24 vertices instead of 8.

Comment: I suspect your `normals` array is wrong. Could you show us what is the content of your normal pointer? Are you changing the normal for each face?

Comment: Normals are kinda wrong but I didn't know that they have impact on texture mapping.. I thought that they only impact lighting... will check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like others, I don't think there is a trick to map your quad textures onto triangles.

The main problem you're experiencing is because of discontinuities in texture coords for each corner. If one corner as some UV coords {u,v} for one face, it doesn't mean it will have the same value for the other two faces that share the vertex. It is possible to find a mapping so that UV is unique at each corner of the cube (shared by 3 faces) and so that all 4 UV values ({0,0}, {1,0}, {1,1} and {0,1}) are present on each face but then some textures would be completely distorted. Try to verify this on a piece of paper: {1,1} is not always at the opposite of {0,0}.

The easiest way to start with, would be to declare explicitly 6 quads, each one of them composed of 2 triangles. That gives you a total of 24 vertices (24 positions and 24 tex coords, interleaved or not) and 36 indices (6 quads composed of two triangles, 6 * 2 * 3 = 36 ).

Here is your code updated to display a cube (there might be some winding problem so I disabled face culling to be sure):

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

static const float vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };


static const int vertexCnt = 6 * 4;

static const GLubyte cube[] = {
     0,  1,  2,  1,  2,  3,
     4,  5,  6,  5,  6,  7,
     8,  9, 10,  9, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 21, 22, 23 
};

static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f
    };

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//glLoadIdentity();

//glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
glRotatef(3.1415927f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cube);
```

Comment: Can you please verify that I correctly map the coordinates in my example above. BTW. Thanks for the info!

Comment: He is trying to draw a single face for now. Discontinuities are not the trouble.

Comment: Yes, question has been edited (used to be for a cube) ;-) The mapping seems correct now so if nothing appears on screen I would start by disabling face culling and GL_COLOR_MATERIAL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You helped me clear some things and I realized that I can't do what I wanted in the way I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to piece through your vertex lists, but my *guess* is that you have your coordinates entirely messed up and mapping wrong, you have specified your index buffer format incorrectly, or you have back-face culling turned on, and some of your vertices are in the wrong order.

As for the texture coordinates themselves, there should be no trick with mapping to triangles in comparison to quads.  You'll just have to have 6 texture coordinates where previously you would have had four, since there are 6 vertices (two duplicates per face).  You may be able to avoid duplication using an index buffer, as you have with your cube.

As for a potential back-face culling problem, you have to define your vertices in the same order every time.  All clockwise, with respect to the direction the texture will be facing, or all counter-clockwise.

What commands are you using to set up your OpenGL pipeline, and what commands are you using to draw those vertices?  Please add the corresponding code to the question.