# OpenGL ES2 Android - Mapping 2D Textures to a GL_TRIANGLES cube

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, uv-mapping

I am trying to map a 256*256 texture onto a cube. When i do so, the front and rear faces are as expected, the left and right faces are inverted in the z direction and the top and bottom faces are "smudged" into a repeating blur. This issue im having has been covered previously, however the only solutions i can find are to use quads, which arent available in Androids implementation of OpenGL ES2.0, or to create a vertex list that contains the verticies for all faces (rather than just the 8 vertices) and then to reference them with indices 0-23 (rather than 0-7).

The code im using that gives the result above is as follows:

```
private float vertices[] = {

    //Front 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //0 Bottom Left
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //1 Bottom Right
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //2 Top Left
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //3 Top Right

    //Back
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, //4 Bottom Left
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, //5 Bottom Right
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, //6 Top Left        
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f //7 Top Right 
};

//Order to draw points in vertices array
private short indices[] = {
    //Faces definition
    0,1,2, 2,1,3, //Front
    5,4,7, 7,4,6, //Back
    1,5,3, 3,5,7, //Right 
    4,0,6, 6,0,2, //Left
    2,3,6, 6,3,7, //Top
    4,5,0, 0,5,1 //Bottom
};

private float textureVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f, //Front
    1.0f, 1.0f, 
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f, //Back
    0.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, //Right 
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,

    1.0f, 1.0f, //Left
    0.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,

    0.0f, 1.0f, //Top
    1.0f, 1.0f, 
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.0f, 1.0f, //Bottom
    1.0f, 1.0f, 
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f

};

public void draw(GL10 gl){
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer); 
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer); 
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indicesBuffer);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

I think the accepted answer in the post [Mapping a square texture to a triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308309/mapping-a-square-texture-to-a-triangle) nearly covers what im after, if it is indeed possible to index and texture in the way that i am expected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vertices` array should match the layout of `textureVertices` array. That means that 8 vertices are not enought to render textured cube, beacuase the vertices at the same position might have different texture coordinates depending on what face they belong to, because `indices` are indices into both the texture and vertex array.

Consider a cube rotated so that an edge faces You. On the left side of the edge, the texture ends. On the right side, the texture starts.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and clear response - i now understand why what im trying to do doesnt work. I didnt appreciate that the indices were used for the texture array too. Is there a way of using a seperate indices array for the texture, or is matching the texture vertices and cube vertices arrays the best practice?